# AOP: Supporting @annotation and @within in one pointcut

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have an annotation which can be placed on a class or a method:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface TestAspectAnnotation {
    String[] tags() default {};
}
```

I want to have a single advising method to handle both class-level and method-level usages:

```java
@Around(value = "@annotation(annotation) || @within(annotation)", argNames = "pjp,annotation")
public Object testAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
                         TestAspectAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {

        String[] tags = annotation.tags();

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        Object proceed = pjp.proceed();
        stopwatch.stop();
        long executionTime = stopwatch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        sendMetrics(tags, executionTime);

        return proceed;

    }
```

This works fine when I annotate a class with `TestAspectAnnotation(tags="foo")`.

However, if I annotate a method, `annotation` argument will be `null`.

Interestingly, if I reverse the order of the pointcut designators (`"@within(annotation) || @annotation(annotation)"`), then I will have the reverse problem: method-level annotations will work fine, but class-level annotations will result in `null` for for the `annotation` argument.

Is there a way have a single pointcut and advice to support the annotation at both a class-level and method-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way have a *single pointcut* and advice

I had a similar problem recently and have tried various options, but to no avail. I ended up splitting the "or" pointcut into two separate pointcuts and calling the same method from both pieces of advice.

I have set up a small demo project to illustrate the working solution that I had set up. I hope this will help you:

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {
    @Around(value = "@within(annotation)", argNames = "pjp,annotation")
    public Object methodAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
        return logTags(pjp, annotation);
    }

    @Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)", argNames = "pjp,annotation")
    public Object classAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
        return logTags(pjp, annotation);
    }

    private Object logTags(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, SomeAnnotation annotation) throws Throwable {
        Stream.of(annotation.tags()).forEach(System.out::println);
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    String[] tags() default {};
}
```

```java
@Service
@SomeAnnotation(tags = {"c", "d"})
public class SomeService {
    @SomeAnnotation(tags = {"a", "b"})
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired private SomeService someService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        someService.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michiel - this is the approach we are considering, but was holding out hope that there might be a cleaner solution. We also tried using 2 different names for the arg (`@annotation(methodAnnotation) || @within(classAnnotation)`), hoping that either one or the other will be `null`, but this doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, correction- it fails to weave at runtime - `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 inconsistent binding`

Comment: The error message explains what is going wrong: the binding is inconsistent as in ambiguous. What if both conditions of a logical OR condition are true? Which annotation instance should be bound?  Imagine you use the annotation on class + method level in the same class. The result is ambiguous, thus binding two variables from different `||` branches to the same method parameter is doomed to fail. Not AspectJ is the problem, your expectation for this to work is kind of illogical.

Comment: @kriegaex So the funny thing is that using the same name works, which, as you say, is ambiguous - you just get `null` in one case, and it's far form obvious which one. The way that fails weaving, we used 2 different names and had 2 different method parameters - which would have no ambiguity. A method-level annotation would populate `methodAnnotation`, class-level - `classAnnotation`. It is this usage `@annotation(annotation) || @within(annotation)` that compiles and weaves fine, but has unexpected runtime behaviour.

Comment: If you have two different parameters, the one from the non-matching OR branch would have an undefined value (not the same as `null` or `0`). The reason it compiles at all is that you compile with _javac_ which only sees annotations with parameters. Only during load-time there can be a pointcut check by the AspectJ weaver. If you would use compile-time weaving via AspectJ compiler, you would get compile errors in both cases: `ambiguous binding of parameter(s) annotation across '||' in pointcut` for shared name and `inconsistent binding` for two different parameter names.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight. I guess you agree that separate advising methods with separate pointcuts is the way to go then? @kriegaex

Comment: I do. It also makes the pointcuts more readable and, if necessary, re-usable. If you worry about duplicated code in your advice methods, you can always factor it out into a helper method taking parameters for the joinpoint and possibly also for the bound annotation.